# How to startup with function keys defaulting to unlock

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

The function keys on my laptop running 20.04 are supposed to be used primarily for hardware control (volume, screen etc). However when the system boots up they default to be used as function keys.
I know that I can lock to the alternate behavior by pressing Fn+Esc once, but I would prefer that when booting the keyboard defaults to the primary behavior.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: is there a setting in BIOS in the same way that caps/num lock can be set?

Comment: @24601 you answer is correct. Many thanks

Comment: I've posted as an answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sorry, finally it did not work. I was misled by the fact the the button light was switched off but the function keys keep to work as functions only. The worst is the fact that now the Fn+Esc does not work as locking combination and I can only use Fn+Function keys to control hardware settings.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is a setting in the BIOS which allows different settings to be accomplished in the same way that the Caps Lock and Number Lock can be set from system boot.

Comment: As I wrote above, finally it did not work. I was misled by the fact the the button light was switched off but the function keys keep to work as functions only. BIOS can only control the Fn+Esc acting as locking combination or not.